# FFMpeg кодировка видео в flv

Tags: flashvideo, php, ffmpeg

Доброго времени суток у меня тут возник такой вопрос... собираюсь поднять видео портал... на данном этапе возник такой вопрос, как лучше сделать перекодировку видео с помощью ffmpeg... пускать в перекодировку видео по 10 видео через cron или выполнять сразу при загрузке видео человеком, сколько одновременно можно будет перекодировать видео на следующей системке: Проц: Core I7, 16гб оперативы... поделитесь личным опытом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перекодировка займет несколько минут. =)
Очень зависит от частоты процессора, нагрузки в данный момент, скорости накопителей, длины видео, оригинального формата, разрешения... Короче, много, много чего еще.
В среднем, на описанной системе лучше запускать CRON при объеме файла более 3-5Мб, потому что иначе в прайм-тайм сайт будет ложиться. 
Мало того. За пару недель работы должна скопиться сатистика(а потом еще и постоянно обновляться!) когда процессор наиболее свободен. В эти часы-то как раз и надо его грузить.
Все эти сложности обычно обходятся внешними серверами(ютьюб, например), пока проект еще на начальной стадии, потому что даже если предположить, что проц частотой около 3ГГц, видео одного человека будет обрабатываться заметное время, учитывая, что большинство пользователей предпочтут скидывать его без каких-либо преобразований.

Comment: Но как-же быть? кроном отрабатывать 1 видео или по 5 - 10... т.к на серверной машине будет ещё стоять основной сайт

Comment: Я же говорю: по нагрузке. =) Измерьте сколько скриптом обрабатывается 100Мб файл(или какой там у вас лимит). Допустим, 10 минут.   
Далее - смотрим на график загруза. Ага! ранним утром с 3 ночи до 6 утра почти никого не бывает на сервере. Это 3х60 = 180 минут. Значит в 3 ночи можно зарядить на обработку 1,8Gb видео. Это все приблизительно.  
Естественно, позже придется написать механизм, подстраивающийся под поток пользователей автоматически.
Все эти сложности из-за того, что для обработки большого количества видео сервер, пожалуй, слабоват.

Comment: Сервер просто "Start - Test"
Дальше больше, есть ли альтернатива ffmpeg? Что-бы не так сильно грузило его :) Немножко вопрос ушел не по теме

Comment: Альтернатив не знаю. Занимался этой темой, когда ffmpeg еще был в ходу.